# how data will be stored in array sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

sqlite query for store all the data in single array.means I have a table where 8 fields are there and I want to retrive all the data in a single array and return array.

Can I do this?

Code from the comment below:

```
public String[] login1(String email) throws SQLException { 
    /* Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
                                    + " WHERE email=? AND password=?", 
                                    new String[]{username,res}); 
    */

    try { 
        /*Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from member where email =" 
                                  + "\""+ email.trim() + "\""+" and password="
                                  + "\""+ res.trim() + "\"", null); 
        */

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select usermasterid,invalidlogincount,password,"
                               + "nextpage,status,user,businessnextpage "
                               + "from member where email " + "\""+ email.trim() 
                               + "\"", null);
```

Comment: Please add some kind of example to clarify what exactly you want to do.

Comment: what example..I want to create a method in sqlite where my method return array

Comment: public String[] login1(String email) throws SQLException 
    {
    // Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE email=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,res});
  try
  {
  //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from member where email =" + "\""+ email.trim() + "\""+" and password="+ "\""+ res.trim() + "\"", null);
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select usermasterid,invalidlogincount,password,nextpage,status,user,businessnextpage from member where email " + "\""+ email.trim() + "\"", null);

Comment: return????how to return array

Comment: Ugh. Please edit your question and add the example there. This is unreadable.

Comment: plz help me if u have any idea for this method

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info in your question, but it should be roughly like this(assuming your data is `int`):

```
public int[] getDBRowAsArray() {
    int[] myArray = new int[8];
    Cursor cursor = yourSQLiteOpenHelper.rawQuery("Your SQL query here", null);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        myArray[i] = cursor.getInt(i);
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume there are 8 records and not fields in the db.

```
public String[] getData(){
    Cursor c = db.query(args...);
    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        int count = c.getCount();
        String[] vals = new String[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            vals[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Table.COLUMN));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
            return vals;
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: yaa this is ok,but I want to create a method where it will return all the data in array format.

Comment: In this method i have written the sqlite qyery also